# Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use fieldname.set() instead

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Custom User Model

```
from django.db import models
# from roles_tasks.models import mst_org_roles
# from organizations.models import config_orgs
# from projects.models import mst_projects
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager



class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,email, first_name, last_name, role_id, org_id, project_id, status, created_by, modified_by, password=None, is_admin=False, is_staff=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("email id is required")

        if not password:
            raise ValueError("password must required")

        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("first_name is required")

        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("last_name is required")

        if not role_id:
            raise ValueError("role_id is required")

        if not org_id:
            raise ValueError("org_id is required")

        if not status:
            raise ValueError("status is required")

        if not created_by:
            raise ValueError("created_by is required")

        if not modified_by:
            raise ValueError("modified_by is required")


        user_obj=self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )   

        user_obj.set_password(password)

        user_obj.first_name=first_name
        user_obj.last_name=last_name
        user_obj.role_id=role_id
        user_obj.org_id=org_id
        user_obj.project_id=project_id
        user_obj.status=status
        user_obj.created_by=created_by
        user_obj.modified_by=modified_by

        user_obj.admin=is_admin
        user_obj.staff=is_staff
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_staffuser(self,email,first_name, last_name, role_id, org_id, project_id, status, created_by, modified_by, password=None):
        user=self.create_user(
            email,
            first_name, 
            last_name, 
            role_id,
            org_id,
            project_id,
            status,
            created_by,
            modified_by,
            password=password,

            is_admin=False,
            is_staff=True
            )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,email,first_name, last_name, role_id, org_id, project_id, status, created_by, modified_by, password=None):
        user=self.create_user(
            email,
            first_name, 
            last_name, 
            role_id,
            org_id,
            project_id,
            status,
            created_by,
            modified_by,    
            password=password,

            is_admin=True,
            is_staff=True
            )

        return user


Status = [
    ('Active', 'Active'),
    ('Inactive', 'Inactive'),
    ('Deleted', 'Deleted')
]

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = None
    last_login = None

    email=models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    admin=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    staff=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    role_id = models.ForeignKey('roles_tasks.mst_org_roles', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    org_id = models.ForeignKey('organizations.config_orgs', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    project_id = models.ManyToManyField('projects.mst_projects', blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices = Status, default = 'Active', max_length = 15)
    created_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, blank=True, null=True)
    modified_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_first_name(self):
        return (self.first_name)

    def get_last_name(self):
        return (self.last_name)

    def get_user_id(self):
        return self.id

    def get_status(self):
        return self.status

    def has_perm(self,perm,obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.email)


    USERNAME_FIELD="email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=['first_name', 'last_name', 'role_id', 'org_id', 'project_id', 'status', 'created_by', 'modified_by']


    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.status

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff
```

I am using Django Rest Framework to create API for this User model. When I try to add the user using this below-mentioned body.

```
{
    "first_name": "FName",
    "last_name": "LName",
    "role_id": 1,
    "org_id": 1,
    "project_id": [1,2],
    "created_by": 1,
    "modified_by": 1,
    "status": "Active",
    "email": "emailaddress@gmail.com",
    "password": "pass12345"
}
```

I am getting this error,

Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use project_id.set() instead.

Can anybody suggest me how to resolve this?

Comment: I edited my answer to include a code example. Please give it a look if you can :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error here. You can create your user passing the user data without the "project_id" (your many-to-many field) key-value, and updating this field later:

```py
user = User.objects.create_user(**user_data)
user.project_id.add(project)
user.project_id.add(other_project)
user.save()
```